# Convert array to string MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an array which I want to use in a query:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [followee] => 267,269,270,271,272,273,275,276,277,278,279 ) )
```

I'm not sure why it returns the message:

> `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.`

Controller:

```
$data['activity'] = $this->home_model->activity($followID);
```

Model:

```
function activity($followID)
{
    $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT name
                    FROM place
                    WHERE userid IN ("'. implode('","', $followID) .'")';

$query = $this->db->query($query_str);
```

Comment: Did you check the dump? var_dump( $this->home_model->activity($followID) );

Comment: It's returning this : bool(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$your_array[0]->followee`.

Comment: Message: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed `WHERE userid IN ("'. implode('","', $followID[0]->followee) .'")';`

Comment: function activity($followID[0]->followee) - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Which variable is `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [followee] => 267,269,270,271,272,273,275,276,277,278,279 ) )` ?

Comment: And this array means `$your_array`, not `$followID`.

Comment: `$followID`is Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [followee] => 267,269,270,271,272,273,275,276,277,278,279 ) )

Comment: So it should be `$this->home_model->activity($followID[0]->followee);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an object in you variable and you don't want to convert that.

The right way, to access the variable would be creating a function inside your class like this:

```
public function getFollowee() {
  return $this -> followee;
}
```

And the way to access it:

```
function activity() {
  $query_str = 'SELECT DISTINCT name FROM place WHERE userid IN ( ' . $stdClass -> getFollowee() . ')';
  $query = $this -> db -> query( $query_str );
}
```